# How can I test a boolean parameter in a NamedQuery with JPA?

Tags: jpa, boolean, jpql, named-query

How can I tell JPA (EclipseLink 2.4) to check a boolean IN parameter whether it is true or false?

```
SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE :inParam = TRUE AND e.x = 'bla'
```

> or

```
SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE :inParam = true AND e.x = 'bla'
```

Doing it as above results in an exception that *TRUE* wouldn't be a valid value for *inParam*.

Comment: Works for me on Hibernate. Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: The literal value for true in Java is `true`, not `TRUE`. That said, since inParam is a parameter, why don't you simply remove it from the where clause and return an empty list directly if the parameter is false?

Comment: JPA/EclipseLink is case insensitive. It doesn't matter if I write TRUE or true. I want to check wheter a filter criteria (inParam) is set to false or true respectively (in conjunction with other validations behind).

Comment: Look like a EclipseLink bug. A simple workaround is to pass the parameter as String and compare it to `'true'`.

Comment: In Spring Boot Jpa query, both TRUE and true works for me