# Spring data JPA custom condition in @Query SQL

Tags: spring-data, hql, spring-repositories

I have the following repository code:

```
        @Query("SELECT " + FIELDS + " FROM Session ssn WHERE "
        + "(ssn.startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ) AND endDate IS     
:closed ? NOT : '' NULL ")
        List<Session> findByDateAndStatus(@Param("startDate)Date startDate,@Param("endDate")Date endDate,@Param("closed")Boolean closed);
```

This code is not working. I want this query to fetch closed sessions or opened sessions based on provided boolean parameter.

```
"AND endDate IS :closed ? NOT : '' NULL "
```

I want to compose HQL string based on my custom boolean parameter. How to do that?

Comment: That's not valid HQL. What should the query do?

Comment: Thanks. This quesry should fetch opened or closed sessions based on boolean parameter.

Comment: I have the feeling you should have two queries instead of this ugly boolean argument. And if really you want a single query, it seems you want `((:closed = true and ssn.endate is not null) or (:closed = false and ssn.enddate is null))`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is you are mixing HQL and Java syntax. Instead, you need to use HQL (or JPQL) syntax to obtain a value that you can properly compare with your bind value. Something like this should work:

```
... AND CASE WHEN (endDate IS NULL) THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE = :closed
```

See also: [How can I test a boolean parameter in a NamedQuery with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033065/how-can-i-test-a-boolean-parameter-in-a-namedquery-with-jpa) and [Is there such thing CASE expression in JPQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427447/is-there-such-thing-case-expression-in-jpql)